# amazing boundedness problem from maximal function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, metric-spaces

Let $n\geq 2$. For any $M>1$, prove that there exists a constant $C_M>1$ such that for any ball $B$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, if we denote $MB$ as the concentric ball of $B$ with $M$ times radius of $B$, then

$$
\int_{MB}\frac{dx}{|x|}\leq C_M\int_B\frac{dx}{|x|}
$$

How to prove?